# Method is being called 8 times and I do not understand why?

Tags: java

My test review is asking "How many times will niceHippo () be called?" and the correct answer is 8. I'm having trouble understanding this as no matter how I look at it I'm not seeing how it results in 8. Please help

```
public class Animals{

    public static String niceHippo()
    {
        String hippo = "Nice Hippo";
        return hippo;
    }

    public static String niceLion(){
        String lion = "Nice Lion";
        return lion;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int count = 13;
        String stringOut = "I love this class ";
        do
        {
            stringOut = "Animals can be messy ";
            for (int order = 1; order < 5; ++ order)
                for (int copy = 1; copy <= 2; copy++)
                    System.out.println(niceHippo());
            System.out.println(niceLion());
        }while (count != 13);

        count = 13;
        while (count > 10)
        {
            count--;
        }

        System.out.println(stringOut + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) for that or look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: *hint*: look at the nested for-loops - `4 x 2 = 8`

Comment: How many times do you think it's being called? Why?

Comment: @shmosel I think I might be understanding it now. Is it 8 because the nested for-loop runs twice each time and the for-loop above it runs 4 consecutive times? If so, does this mean the count variable is irrelevant for the amount of times niceHippo() is called?

Comment: Indeed it is...

Comment: Nothing in the loop is changing the count variable from its initial value of 13. So the do loop will execute once, and the where clause will cause it to not execute again.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are iterating outer loop `for (int order = 1; order < 5; ++ order)` for order = 1 to 4 and for each iteration copy value `for (int copy = 1; copy <= 2; copy++)` will be 1 and 2 and `niceHippo` is called from inner loop, so as a result `niceHippo` is being called 8 times

Answer (score 0):

For the loop using copy, each time that's ran you print nice hippo twice because `copy <=2`
Then the loop using order is going to ask that copy loop to run 4 times because `order <5`

so in the end nice hippo prints 8 times because one loop prints nice hippo twice and its asked to do that 4 times by the outer loop.